# Stacktrace in LogCat

Tags: android, stack, strace

I use Eclipse to develop Android App, when i have error in logcat is only information:

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dd8438)
```

no stack trace or any information what is wrong in my code.

Comment: to say what's wrong with your code we should take a look on the code at first

Answer (score 1):

If you look through the stack trace, you will see a "Caused by..." line (sometimes more than one). The last one of those is the important one.
     Check properly use "findviewById" element for your code, check for all resources.